# BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11.6 using ruby-build 20160913) how to solve this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby & Rails. Can't install with this error :

```
Downloading ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.3.1...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11.6 using ruby-build 20160913)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/1p/hwq8dn9x7b76xf8_b1kg5z800000gn/T/ruby-build.20160922084422.20582
Results logged to /var/folders/1p/hwq8dn9x7b76xf8_b1kg5z800000gn/T/ruby-build.20160922084422.20582.log

Last 10 log lines:
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/1p/hwq8dn9x7b76xf8_b1kg5z800000gn/T/ruby-build.20160922084422.20582/ruby-2.3.1/./miniruby (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/1p/hwq8dn9x7b76xf8_b1kg5z800000gn/T/ruby-build.20160922084422.20582/ruby-2.3.1/./miniruby (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

make: *** [encdb.h] Trace/BPT trap: 5
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and after executing:

```
xcode-select --install
```

I was then able to complete the ruby compilation.

Comment: Just follow yours instuctions and everything work well ! thanks alot. :D